# How many ideals are there in $B(H)^{**}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

It is well-known (and easy to prove) that the only closed ideals of $B(\ell_2)$ are $\{0\}$, $B(\ell_2)$ and $K(\ell_2)$, the ideal of compact operators on $\ell_2$. I am curious whether we know what is the lattice of closed, two-sided ideals of $B(\ell_2)^{**}$.

Comment: The second dual of $B(H)$? Are you mad??

Comment: You could find something in Matthew Daws Ph.D. thesis

Comment: @userNaN Do you have a specific reference? I'm reasonably familiar with Daws's thesis and he looks at the lattice of closed 2-sided ideals in $B(\ell_p(I))$ for higher cardinals $I$, but IIRC nothing on ideals in $B(H)^{**}$

Comment: My bad, Daws discussed only semisimplicity of $\mathcal{B}(E)^{**}$